# deploy after gitlab runner completes build

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm want to use gitlab runners to deploy a successfully built docker image but I am not sure how to use the deploy stage in .gitlab-ci.yml to do this. The build log shows the database is properly created on the docker image during the build process.

I use docker locally on a Mac (OSX 10.11.6) to build my docker container. Gitlab is running remotely. I registered a specific local runner to handle the build. When I push changes to my project, gitlab CI runs the build script to create a test database. What happens to the image after it's built? There is no docker image for the completed build listed on my local machine. The gitlab-runner-prebuilt-x86_64 is a barebones linux image that isn't connected with the build.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/

```
>gitlab-ci-multi-runner list
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/Users/username/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
local-docker-executor                               Executor=docker Token=[token] URL=http://gitlab.url/ci

>docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gitlab-runner-prebuilt-x86_64   f6fdece             [id1]        25 hours ago        50.87 MB
php7                            latest              [id2]        26 hours ago        881.8 MB
ubuntu                          latest              [id3]        13 days ago         126.6 MB
docker                          latest              [id4]        2 weeks ago         104.9 MB
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yml
image: php7:latest

# build_image:
#   script:
#     - docker build -t php7 .

# Define commands that run before each job's script
# before_script:
#   - docker info

# Define build stages
  # First, all jobs of build are executed in parallel.
  # If all jobs of build succeed, the test jobs are executed in parallel.
  # If all jobs of test succeed, the deploy jobs are executed in parallel.
  # If all jobs of deploy succeed, the commit is marked as success.
  # If any of the previous jobs fails, the commit is marked as failed and no jobs of further stage are executed.
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy     

variables:
  db_name: db_test
  db_schema: "db_test_schema.sql"

build_job1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - service mysql start
    - echo "create database $db_name" | mysql -u root
    - mysql -u root $db_name < $db_schema
    - mysql -u root -e "show databases; use $db_name; show tables;"
    #- echo "SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');" | mysql -u root   
    #- echo "run unit test command here"
  #Defines a list of tags which are used to select Runner  
  tags:
    - docker

deploy_job1:
  stage: deploy
  #this script is run inside the docker container
  script:
    - whoami
    - pwd
    - ls -la
    - ls /
    #Usage: docker push [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG]
    #Push an image or a repository to a registry
    - docker push deploy:latest
  #gitlab runners will look for and run jobs with these tags 
  tags:
    - docker
```

`config.toml`:

```toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "local-docker-executor"
  url = "http://gitlab.url/ci"
  token = "[token]"
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir = "/Users/username/DOCKER_BUILD_DIR"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```

`Dockerfile`:

```docker
FROM ubuntu:latest

#https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive                                      
ENV MYSQL_USER mysql                                                    
ENV MYSQL_DATA_DIR /var/lib/mysql                                       
ENV MYSQL_RUN_DIR /run/mysqld                                           
ENV MYSQL_LOG_DIR /var/log/mysql                                        
ENV DB_NAME "db_test"                                               
ENV DB_IMPORT "db_test_schema.sql"                                  

# RUN apt-get update && \
#       apt-get -y install sudo
# RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo
# USER docker
# CMD /bin/bash

RUN apt-get update                                                      \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server      
 # \
 # && rm -rf ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR}                                          \
 # && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD ${DB_IMPORT} /tmp/${DB_IMPORT}


# #RUN /usr/bin/sudo service mysql start                                                    \
# RUN service mysql start                                                   \
#  && mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME"                           \
#  && mysql -u root $DB_NAME < /tmp/$DB_IMPORT

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
    && export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-cli php-xdebug php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mysql php-memcached php-pear php7.0-dev php7.0-json vim git-core libssl-dev libsslcommon2-dev openssl libssl-dev \
    && a2enmod headers 

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log && \
    ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log
RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR


#VOLUME [ "/var/www/html" ]
WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80 3306

#ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/sbin/apache2" ]
#CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]

#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but your question is more related to Dockers than Gitlabs, right?

Comment: I'd like to have a GitLab runner deploy my docker image. To do that, it looks like I need to have docker running as a service on the image either through a socket or by having docker installed on the image.

Answer (score 2):

You're not building any docker image on CI.

You are using php7 image from DockerHub to execute all jobs. This includes the job `deploy_job1`, that are trying to use `docker` binary to push an image (`deploy:latest`) that is not inside that container. Additionaly, I think that `docker` binary is not included on the `php7` image.

I guess that you want to push the image that you build locally on your Mac, isn't it? In that case, you need to use another runner, which its executor should be `shell`. On that scenario, you will have 2 runners, one using docker to run the `build_job1` job, and another one to push the locally built image. But there is a better solution that build manually the docker image, and it's to make GitLab CI to build it.

So, modifing your `.gitlab-ci.yml` (removing your comments, adding mines for explanation):

```ruby
# Removed global image definition

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy     

variables:
  db_name: db_test
  db_schema: "db_test_schema.sql"

build_job1:
  stage: build
  # Use image ONLY in docker runner
  image: php7:latest
  script:
    - service mysql start
    - echo "create database $db_name" | mysql -u root
    - mysql -u root $db_name < $db_schema
    - mysql -u root -e "show databases; use $db_name; show tables;"
  # Run on runner with docker executor, this is ok
  tags:
    - docker

deploy_job1:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    # Build the docker image first, and then push it
    - docker build -t deploy:latest .
    - docker push deploy:latest
  # Run on runner with shell executor, set proper tag
  tags:
    - docker_builder
```

When you register the new runner, set executor as `shell` and tags `docker_builder`. I'm asuming that you have installed docker engine on your Mac.

On the other hand, this example makes no sense, at least for me. The `build` stage does nothing, as the container is ephemeral. I guess you should do that on the Dockerfile.